# Get the highest values of a data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My html looks like

```html
<div id="container">
     <div class="right" data-x="1" data-y="1" ></div>
     <div class="right" data-x="2" data-y="1" ></div>
     <div class="right" data-x="3" data-y="1" ></div>
     <div class="right" data-x="4" data-y="1" ></div>
</div>
```

How to get max/min value of data-x/data-y using jquery?

Comment: How? By [looking at the API](http://api.jquery.com) and taking a stab at it. SO is not a "write this code for me" service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
var containerChilds = document.getElementById("container").children;
var max = 0;
for ( var counter =0; counter < containerChilds.length; counter++)
{
  var value = containerChilds[counter].getAttribute("data-x");
  if ( max < value )
  {
    max = value;
  }
}
console.log(max);
```

In jQuery

```
var max = 0;
$("#container div.right[data-x]").each(function(){
   var value = $(this).attr("data-x");
   max = max < value ? value : max;
});
console.log(max);
```

Answer (score 0):

Generate array of values of `data-x` and `data-y` values using **[`map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/)** and **[`get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/)**. Then use **[`Math.min`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min)** and **[`Math.max`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max)** with **[`apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)** to get maximum and minimum value from array.

```js
// generate array of `data-x` attribute
var arr1 = $('[data-x]').map(function() {
  return $(this).data('x');
}).get();
// generate array of `data-y` attribute
var arr2 = $('[data-y]').map(function() {
  return $(this).data('y');
}).get();

console.log(
  Math.min.apply(Math, arr1),
  Math.min.apply(Math, arr2),
  Math.max.apply(Math, arr1),
  Math.max.apply(Math, arr2)
)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div class="right" data-x="1" data-y="1"></div>
  <div class="right" data-x="2" data-y="1"></div>
  <div class="right" data-x="3" data-y="1"></div>
  <div class="right" data-x="4" data-y="1"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply same thing for `data-y`

```js
var arrDataX=new Array();
var arrDataY=new Array();

$('div.right').each(function(index){
  arrDataX.push($(this).attr("data-x"));
  arrDataY.push($(this).attr("data-y"));
});

var minValue=arrDataX.sort()[0];
var maxValue=arrDataX.sort()[arrDataX.length-1];

alert("Min - "+minValue+", Max - "+maxValue);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
     <div class="right" data-x="1" data-y="1" ></div>
     <div class="right" data-x="2" data-y="1" ></div>
     <div class="right" data-x="3" data-y="1" ></div>
     <div class="right" data-x="4" data-y="1" ></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var all = $("#container").find(".right");
var max_x =0;
var max_y =0;
var min_x =1;
var min_y =1;
$.each(all,function(k,v){
  if(max_x<$(v).attr("data-x"))
      max_x = $(v).attr("data-x");
  if(min_x>$(v).attr("data-x"))    
     min_x = $(v).attr("data-x");

  if(max_y<$(v).attr("data-y"))
    max_y = $(v).attr("data-y");
  if(min_y>$(v).attr("data-y"))    
     min_y = $(v).attr("data-y");   
})

alert("max_x:"+max_x+" max_y:"+max_y+" min_x:"+min_x+" min_y:"+min_y);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sum1/L94ugfyp/